# jQuery.load a WordPress page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, .htaccess

I use jQuery.load to load a localhost URL (eg: localhost/wp/contact) which it works fine, but once I put it online, and change the URL devric.Co.cc/contact this does not load anything, would this got to do a with htaccess? But its set with URL rewrite, and its working if you go directly to the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script requests the following URL `http://contact/`, there is not need in window.location.pathname.
Try this code

```
   $('#contactframe').load( '/contact', function(){
        $('#contactframe').animate({
            'margin-top':0
        });
    });
```

Comment: i found out the reason, shouldn't use window.load.pathname, was using that for the localhost

Answer (score 0):

You could load your page in a php file on your server and after that load it via jQuery to your website.

I do not think that cross-domain works with jQuery.load.